# .htaccess rewrite dont work

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This have been asked allot around the internet and here on stackoverflow.
But i cant get it to work. (first time using .htacces)
What im trying to do is some simple stuff:

1. remove `www` from url.
2. remove `.php` from url.
3. remove `/index` from homepage if linked back to it.

according to my webhosting company this is what they use:
Apache 2.2+ and PHP 5.3+ - MySQL 5.1+

the .htacces file is located in the root folder with index.php
i have tried allot of stuff but this is what i got right now:

```
RewriteEngine On
#www to non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.se$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.se/$1 [L,R=301]

#remove .php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.se$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !internal=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [L,R=301]

#remove /index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

thanks beforehand for any help you can provide.

Comment: what do the rewrite logs say?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"?

Comment: You have not said which of those three does not work for you and what happens instead.

Comment: should __ADD /INDEX.PHP__ /index.php?/$1 be /index.php?$1

Comment: You _did_ name your file `.htaccess`, not `.htacces`, right?

Comment: none of them work.
yes its htaccess not htacces :)

Comment: Its working now! i misspelled something in the actual code.
but the remove .php wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `.htaccess` in the wrong way.

You mustn't use htaccess to generate a friendly url, **you must use it to translate a friendly url into the real one** :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect www.mysite.se to mysite.se
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.se$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.se/$1 [L,R=301]

#redirect mysite.se/page to mysite.se/page.php (transparent)
#as this rule is extremely permissive, we desactivate it when we're calling
#a real file, to avoid this kind of situation : mysite.se/img/mylogo.jpg.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

#redirect mysite.se/index to mysite.se/ (visible)
RewriteRule ^index$ / [L,R=301]
```

In your code, **use friendly urls**, and let htaccess redirect its.

If you're not using this way, you'll got into a self-destructive pattern, trying to redirect `page.php` to `page` (to get nice urls), and redirect `page` to `page.php` (because your application only know `page.php`).

Comment: so i should write my urls like without .php?

Comment: Yes, use urls without .php everywhere.

Comment: thats inconvenient :(

Comment: Htaccess rewrite rules aren't something you define in the middle of a project. It's part of the basic configuration, part of the architecture, you **must** think about it when you starts a project. Anyway, even your old `.php` urls will works, but you may have some problems (I'm thinking about form validation for example, if you send POST data to `/validate`, htaccess will redirect you to `/validate.php` and you'll loose your POST datas)

Comment: ok thx, i will think of that for the next project!
I got the www to non-www to anyways :) Thx for your answers